# Installing libraspberrypi-bin on Ubuntu Server 20.04 for Raspberry Pi4

Tags: ppa, raspberrypi

A year ago I was running Ubuntu Server 19.04 on rPI4. I needed `vcgencmd` so I had to install `libraspberrypi-bin`. I have notes on how to clone the userland repository, edit few files, and compile it from source. I did it last year and it works fine up to this day.

I got another rPI4 today and need to install it again, however it looks like the files in repo changed since and my own obscure method doesn't work any more.

I googled around and following [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi) guide. I've added `ppa:ubuntu-raspi2/ppa` repo to my fresh Ubuntu 20.04 however after running `apt update` I get the following error:

```
root@ubuntu:/tmp# sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-raspi2/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports InRelease
Hit:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security InRelease
Err:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-raspi2/ppa/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::15 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-raspi2/ppa/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

It looks like that repo was last updated over 2 years ago I guess this guide is also out of date.

My question in short: how to get libraspberrypi-bin on Ubuntu 20.04 for Raspberry Pi 4?

Comment: Keep in mind the PPA you pointed at does not have a Focal variant yet.  Either the maintainer of that PPA has to update the PPA, or it's suffering from bitrot and cannot be used.

Comment: I am adding this hack here, in case no-one answers - I followed the hints in this post https://sungup.github.io/2020/01/02/Collecting-Thermal-Metrics-on-Raspberry-Pi-4.html which is against 19.10(eoan) but if you change eoan to focal in the instructions it works fine for 20.04, give it a try.